# Choosing a model for zero-inflated self-reported spending outcome

Tags: distributions, zero-inflation

My outcome variable is individual's self-reported spending ($), which is distributed as follows (rounded to integers). I want to add several independent variables to examine their relationships, and I have two questions.

1. The outcome is zero-inflated but I am uncertain what model to adopt. The dependent variable is not theoretically count data but continuous. It could perhaps technically treated as counts if the values are rounded to integers. Would this be a feasible approach? If yes, perhaps zero-inflated negative binomial models could be adopted?

I also considered zero-inflated gamma distribution since it can handle continuous variables. However, I did not find a R package which could simultaneously estimate both the binary and continuous part of the function. If I estimate them separately, I am not certain, how to i) get one log likelihood (instead of two) to compare models, and ii) easily make predictions on new data. Thus, providing material / R code would be highly valued if you recommend zero inflated gamma.

2. The data has other spikes than 0, such as in the 50 dollar and 100 dollar area. Clearly, these spikes result from the fact that the data is self-reported. I am uncertain how I should take these spikes into account in the modelling. Could you provide recommendations on that?

[image]